# TimescaleDB pgbackrest backups helm chart ERROR: [029]: unable to find child 'IsTruncated':0 in node 'ListAllMyBucketsResult'

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes-helm, timescaledb, ceph, pgbackrest

I'm trying to set up backups in pgbackrest/timescaledb. I'm using timescaledb-single chart [version 0.33.1](https://stackoverflow.com) ,
Here are my chart values:

```
timescaledb-single:
  replicaCount: 2

  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 3Gi # K8s node allocatable memory - 250 Mi for system pods
    requests:
      cpu: "2"
      memory: 3Gi # K8s node allocatable memory - 250 Mi for system pods
  patroni:
    bootstrap:
      dcs:
        postgresql:
          parameters:
            max_wal_size: 80GB  # 80% of the Volume Size
            min_wal_size: 2GB
            shared_buffers: 1000MB  # 25% of memory limits
            work_mem: 64MB
            max_connections: 1620 # LEAST({MemoryLimit/9531392}, 5000)
            temp_file_limit: 10GB   
  secrets:
    pgbackrest:
      PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_REGION: US
      PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_KEY: XXXX
      PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_KEY_SECRET: XXXX
      PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_BUCKET: use1-example-store-1
      PGBACKREST_REPO1_S3_ENDPOINT: ibra.net/use1-object-store-1

  backup:
    enabled: true
    pgBackRest:
      repo1-type: s3
      repo1-s3-region: US
      repo1-s3-endpoint: use1-example-store-1.ibra.net:443
    jobs:
      - name: full-daily
        type: full
        schedule: "10 15 * * *"
```

Pgbackrest is able to acquire connection with ceph bucket but is getting below error during `pgbackrest stanza-create`:

```
ERROR: [029]: unable to find child 'IsTruncated':0 in node 'ListAllMyBucketsResult'
```

I've tried to see if Ceph has support for list-objects-v2 API which contains 'isTruncated' flag and it seems that yes:

```
aws --endpoint-url=https://use1-example-store-1.ibra.net s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket use1-example-store-1 --no-paginate
{
    "IsTruncated": false,
    "Name": "use1-example-store-1",
    "Prefix": "",
    "MaxKeys": 1000,
    "EncodingType": "url",
    "KeyCount": 0
}
```

Someone is able to help?

Comment: Hi Marek, this helm chart is discontinued. I'd recommend you migrate to another operator. Take a look on stackgres, zalando and other operators. This one was used by promscale and was discontinued when promscale stopped development.